# kdb+/q script how to encode-decode string

Tags: kdb

I am looking for encoding/decoding a string in q script
.Q.x10,.Q.j10,.Q.x12 and .Q.j12 does not seem to meet requirement.
e.g. 
I want to encode "Hello world" and I should be able to decode it further

Comment: Encode it to what?

Comment: apologies for delayed response ,Encode I meant  some cryptic text such that no one could read it

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the default .Q.j10 and .Q.x10 don't allow for the space character `" "` since the space character is not in the default alphabet used:

```
q).Q.j10
64/:?["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"]
```

If you look at the "tip" comment in the official documentation: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qj10-encode-binhex

you'll see that they suggest creating your own .Q.j10/.Q.x10 functions where the space character is the first character in your custom alphabet. Your alphabet still has to be only 64 characters though, so you would have to get rid of either the `+` or `/` (or replace them with another character of your choosing).

A similar question came up on the k4 topicbox on August 16th 2019 (subject "b64 encode") where Geo Carncross came up with this solution for b64 decoding:

```
q).Q.btoa"Hello World!"
"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
q)
q){c:sum x="=";neg[c]_"c"$raze 256 vs'64 sv'0N 4#.Q.b6?x}"SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
"Hello World!"
```

I haven't tested the latter though.